# Factoring $a^m + 1$, an odd prime

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization

Why is it that if $a^m + 1$, an odd prime, with $m = kl$, and $l$ odd.

We get:

$$a^m + 1 = (a^k + 1)(a^{k(l-1)} - a^{k(l-2)} + \dots + a^k + 1)?$$

What is the name of this property?

Comment: I have fixed your formatting, but I don't understand what your question is. You might want to consider rephrasing it.

Comment: It's the formula for the sum of a geometric progression (but there's a sign error in the current version).

Comment: What does the equality you mention has to do with $a^m+1$ being an odd prime?

Comment: Oh it probably doesn't it just came from a question where $a^m + 1$ was an odd prime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is odd we have $$\frac{1+x^n}{1+x}=\frac{1-(-x)^n}{1-(-x)}=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}=\cdots?$$

In your case if $m=kl$ take $x=a^k$. What this is saying is that if $m$ is odd and $a^m+1$ is an odd prime, $m$ must be prime as well.

Comment: so where does m=kl fit into the equation I only see n's in the equation though

Comment: @DJ_ In your case your $n$ is $l$.

Comment: Still not sure how this gets back to $a^m + 1$...

Comment: @DJ_ "...take $x=a^k$..."